# How can I get Selenium WebDriver (Java) to click this button?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new at using Selenium WebDriver to automate test cases. So far (using Selenium and Java),  I am able to open the testing website, enter the username and password, and log in. After logging in, however, the user is re-directed to a screen with a security warning that must be accepted before they can access the actual website. To do this, they must click on a button called "I Agree". I can't get Selenium to click the button and, without it, I can't get to the rest of the site to automate. Here is the HTML for the button:

```
<form name="landingHandlerSF" method="post" action="/apps/bap/secLandingHandler.do">
<input name="userAgreedTerms" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="submit" value="landing" type="hidden">
<input name="buttonAction" value="I Agree" onclick="setValue('agreetoTerms', 'Y')" type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the code I have tried (which doesn't work):

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.name("buttonAction"));
button.click();
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: What is the error? It would help in getting it debugged much better.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what exactly happens? What do you mean by `doesn't work`? Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: Pradeep's answer was the issue, but thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, page is redirecting to new html page but driver will be pointing to parent page(Login page in your case) , so you may have to switch to `child window` in order to click on  <kbd>I Agree</kbd>  button.

The following code will switch the driver away from the current window (ie, the login window) to the new window (ie, the security warning). After clicking  <kbd>I Agree</kbd>  that security warning will be closed and the driver will switch back automatically

```
String thisWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
for (String windowHandle : windowHandles) {
    if (!windowHandle.contains(thisWindow)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
    }
}
```

If it is not navigating to new page then it must be under some `iframes` , in that case you may need to switch to frame and click the button.

Hope this will work.
Try this and let me know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to inject JavaScript code into the browser?

```
driver.executeScript("setValue('agreetoTerms', 'Y')");
```

or

```
driver.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('buttonAction')[0].click()");
```

Comment: Pradeep's answer was the issue, but thank you for your help :)