# Selenium Webdriver : How can I find the XPath of an undetectable popup message?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

It is not possible to select a popup message and find its XPath why? Is there any way to fetch the XPath of the popup message?

Comment: Popups can be implemented in different ways. You'll need to provide more details. The most understood definition would be when a separate window opens for your browser... in which case you need to tell selenium to switch windows. And what do you mean by 'undetectable' ? Do you just mean that you can't select it, or is there something special about *this* popup that makes it 'undetectable'.

Comment: @sytech  Is it a browser popup or windows popup?

Comment: Add a breakpoint in JS code before the popup appears, and try to go step by step until the popup appears. Then you can use devtool to inspect it.

Comment: This might answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232386/how-can-i-get-selenium-webdriver-java-to-click-this-button/48232685#48232685

Comment: Which kind of `popup` are you referring to? Can you share a `snapshot`?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a modal popup, you need to use driver.SwitchTo().Alert 
If it is windows form, you can do nothing